# Resources$NotFoundException при использовании BottomNavigationView на устройствах с API 21, 22, 23

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

В главной активности проекта юзаю **BottomNavigationView** с 3 элементами.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:background="@color/bottom_nav_bgColor"
app:elevation="@dimen/bottom_nav_elevation"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/state_bottom_nav_text"
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_main" />
```

Сама менюшка выглядит следующим образом (menu/**bottom_nav_main.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
android:id="@+id/action_one"
android:title="@string/action_one"
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/state_action_one"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</item>

<item
android:id="@+id/action_two"
android:title="@string/action_two"
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/state_action_two"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</item>

<item
android:id="@+id/action_three"
android:title="@string/action_three"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:enabled="true"
android:icon="@drawable/state_action_three">
</item>

</menu>
```

Иконки устанавливаются как **drawable-состояния** (res/drawable/**state_action_one.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_one_pressed" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_one_activity" />
</selector>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что когда я запускаю приложение, оно **крашится на устройствах с API 21, 22, 23** (т.е. на lollipop и marshmallow) со следующим содержанием:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.dev.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:105)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6314)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.dev.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:105) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6314) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at 
com.dev.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:105) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6314) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/state_action_one.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0701d1
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2872)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2756)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:920)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:463)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.initialize(BottomNavigationItemView.java:105)
at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:523)
at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:62)
at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:254)
at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:187)
at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<ini
```

Использовал в активности следующий код:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

И также добавил в конфиги:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

На **API 19 (KitKat) и API 24< все работает нормально**, а вот на вышеуказанных апишках - вылетает.
Ребята, может кто сталкивался с таким или знает как решить эту проблему, будьте добры, подскажите способы или хотя бы что такого особенного в этих API (21,22,23) что они не хотят видеть ресурсы.

**P.S**
Погуглив подобные вопросы, увидел, что проблема кроется в элементе меню , т.к. [здесь используется **градиент**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693942/4512868).
Окей, заменив заливку градиента на однотонную, приложение стало запускаться.
Однако возник вопрос... Почему? Т.к. у меня **есть другие векторные иконки с градиентной заливкой** (однако они не используются в **селекторах** и **меню**).
Поэтому,переместил свой взгляд на строку *android:icon="@drawable/state_action_one"*, т.е. где используется селектор.
Может ли кто-то обьяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: Все версии компонент appcompat имеют одну версию?

Comment: @SergeMarkov да, конечно. Юзаю com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0